# MYSQL Query calculate percentage of emails not null

Tags: mysql, sql, percentage

I have these two queries.

*Caluculates count of emails that are null*

`SELECT COUNT(*) as invalid_email FROM distinct_customers WHERE c_email IS NULL;`

*Calculates count of every email*

`SELECT COUNT(distinct c_number) as total FROM distinct_customers;`

I am trying to combine those to queries so that it gives me a percentage of valid emails (not null)

I tried a couple of ways but I am not a mysql expert.

Mathematically it should be

643(null emails)*100 / 1292(total emails)

Comment: Why are you using `distinct` in the second query?  What if there are multiple rows for a given `c_number`, some with emails and some without?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

```
SELECT (COUNT(case when c_email IS NULL then 1 end)*100.00)/
        COUNT(distinct c_number) as percentage
FROM distinct_customers
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest method is to use `AVG()` -- assuming you want this by rows:

```
SELECT AVG(c_email IS NOT NULL) as invalid_email_ratio,
       100 * AVG(c_email IS NOT NULL) as invalid_email_percentile           
FROM distinct_customers ;
```